# Yii - Show/Hide Div with Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

Yii- show/hide div based on radio selection. it's working fine. but in that div required fields are there. after page refresh(if any mandatory fields not fulfill) the div is not showing.

```
$(function() {
$("#placed").hide();
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio[name*="PlacementInfo[status]"]', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'PlacementInfo_status_0') {
        $('#placed').show();
    } else {
        $('#placed').hide();
    }
});});
```

• I'm not using radio button checked property on page load.

• I'm using yii-scenario(for required fields)

```
array('organization,role,joiningdate,location,salary,completedyear', 'required','on'=>'checked'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to determine the status on page load also. Try

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#PlacementInfo_status_0').is(":checked")) {
        $('#placed').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#placed').hide();
    }
    $(document).on('click', 'input:radio[name*="PlacementInfo[status]"]', function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'PlacementInfo_status_0') {
            $('#placed').show();
        } else {
            $('#placed').hide();
        }
    });
});
```